How do I set the DEFAULT value for a non-nullable column to the TOP 1 result of a SELECT query?
I'm trying to add a non-nullable column to an already existing table, and I read somewhere that I need a DEFAULT value in order to do that.
The value for the DEFAULT needs to be equal to the TOP 1 user_id result of the SELECT query shown below. I tried using a variable, but this didn't work.
This is what I tried:
DECLARE @latestuserid AS int
SELECT TOP 1 @latestuserid = user_id from Employees ORDER BY user_id DESC
ALTER TABLE Control ADD nextuserid INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (@latestuserid)

However I get the error:

Variables are not allowed in the ALTER TABLE statement.

If I can't use variables, how do I do this if I don't always know the exact value of that SELECT statement?

You can't default it like that in the alter table, you have to alter it to a nullable column, update the values, then change it to non-nullable

Or you could use dynamic sql

Do NOT add a "nextuserid" column to a table. Nothing good will come of this.

I think @JoelCoehoorn is right.  What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

You can first define the desired column as nullable and then execute an update command for the new column. After that, you can make it not nullable.

As you've noticed, you cannot directly use variables or dynamic SQL in the ALTER TABLE statement for the DEFAULT constraint in SQL Server.
You may go for an alternative approach using a temporary default value, and then changing it once you get the dynamic value.
Here are the steps that you may want to try:

Add the column with a temporary default value:
Use a safe placeholder value that doesn't conflict with its potential valid data.
ALTER TABLE Control
ADD nextuserid INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1;


Determine the latest user_id and modify the constraint:
Find the latest user_id, then add the new default constraint.
-- Fetch the latest user_id
DECLARE @latestuserid INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @latestuserid = user_id FROM Employees ORDER BY user_id DESC;

-- Add a new default constraint
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE Control ADD CONSTRAINT DF_NextUserID DEFAULT ' 
           + CAST(@latestuserid AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' FOR nextuserid';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


Update existing rows:
Optionally, if there were some rows in the table prior to adding the nextuserid column, you can update them if necessary.
UPDATE Control
SET nextuserid = @latestuserid
WHERE nextuserid = -1;



I hope this helps you!
